# What does Spotlight consider to be a 'Document'?

Tags: spotlight, search

I have noticed that the Finder's **Recent** Smart Search Folder doesn't show several type of 'app document' file.

The same is true if I create a new Smart Folder with the criterion set to `Kind = Document`.
(You can sort through the results by Kind in a List View)

For instance: Affinity Suite documents, such as `.afpub`, and `.afdesign` are **not** included.
Omnigraffle and OmniOutliner files **are** included.
Files from other apps, such as Finale (`.musx`) and Dorico (`.dorico`) are not included.

If I change the search criteria to `Kind = Other: Affinity`, then I get the Affinity documents, so it's not like Spotlight hasn't indexed them.

**Does anyone know on what basis Spotlight considers a file to be a document?**

These 'missing files' are the native document format for these apps, so they are listed in the apps' Info.plist, under `CFBundleDocumentTypes`.

Comment: I don't know how Apple defines document, but I do know how it is defined in current ISO/IEC 2382-23 standard 'Information technology. Vocabulary. Part 23, Text processing': '23.01.05 document: A named, structured unit of text and possibly images that can be stored, edited, retrieved, and exchanged among systems or users as a separate unit.'. I assume that 'structured unit of text' is an important factor for Spotlight as well.

Comment: Hmm. Given that some third-party "app-savey-files" ARE included, I think it's likely to be some kind of parameter that can be set somewhere, rather than just using an ISO definition.

Answer (score 3):

Spotlight will only classify a file format as a 'Document' if there is a Spotlight importer for that file type.

Third-party applications with 'non-standard' file types (e.g. not text, graphics) will need to define an importer for their formats.

This way, the document metadata and possible also contents can be added to the Spotlight index.

Comment: I thought the bundle info might be involved. But these file formats ARE the apps' native document file types, and are listed in CFBundleDocumentTypes. Is there some other key that flags them as "Documents" for the purposes of Spotlight.

Comment: Yes, I didn’t have time to detail it yesterday, the application also needs to define an importer for Spotlight for each format, if it is not text/RTF/PDF or similar standard format. This way the document metadata and possible also contents can be added to the Spotlight index

Comment: So it's only a document if there's a Spotlight importer? Yes, that seems to fit.
If you change your answer to that, I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @benwiggy! :-)

Comment: Actually, I've found some document types with Spotlight importers that Spotlight still doesn't describe as "Documents".

Comment: Yes, ofcourse - there’s plenty of other file types than documents: images, videos, audio, etc. This question was about why a document was not classified by Spotlight as a document - and that’s because there was no importer for it. So a document needs an importer to be classified as a document. It doesn’t mean that every format that has an importer is classified as a document.

Comment: I don't understand how those two sentences don't contradict each other. A file type for an app I have has an importer, but it still isn't a "document", according to Spotlight.

Comment: I’m not sure how to describe it any clearer. An importer can tell Spotlight that a file is a document. Then Spotlight reports it as a document. An importer could instead tell Spotlight that a file is something else, and then Spotlight does not report it as a document.

Comment: Ah: OK, so you're saying there's a flag or some such that the developer has to specifically mark. However, there's another file that doesn't have an importer and does show up in Recents as a 'document'.

Comment: This was about Affinity Suite documents - those files you mention are not from Affinity Suite. Some document types have importers built in to Spotlight - they do not require a separate importer. There’s no built in importer for Affinity Suite documents.